# Typescript generics - Type 'X' cannot be used to index type 'Y'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, I am having issues with this part of the code (second line inside method remove causing the problem):

```
export abstract class Collection<T, K> {
    private data: Array<T> = [];

    add(item: T): void {
        this.data.push(item);
    }

    remove<J extends keyof K>(item: T, byKey: J): boolean {
        let index = this.data.findIndex((i: T) => i[byKey] === item[byKey]);
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
        return index != -1 ? true : false;
    }

    getAll(): Array<T> {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is the best way to explain the problem, here you can find [repo](https://bitbucket.org/dragol/ts/src/master/)

Comment: it  should be `remove<J extends keyof T>(` since you access  `T` by key

Comment: @Eldar unfortunately, that is not what I actually need. In the example, T is like model, K is modelProps and then I want to remove item from collection by providing whole model and key as deletion criteria, like so:
customCollection.remove(customModelInstance, 'keyFromModel'); - that is why I have introduced J type.

Comment: If your implementation is correct it should be `keyof T` or your implementation has to change..

Comment: So, I have change it, and this is the outcome [link](http://prntscr.com/qh7wc5)...

Comment: I guess this is the solution:

`
import { Model } from './model';

export abstract class Collection<T extends Model<K>, K> {
 private data: Array<T> = [];

 add(item: T): void {
  this.data.push(item);
 }

 remove<J extends keyof K>(item: T, byKey: J): boolean {
  let index = this.data.findIndex((i: T) => i.get(byKey) === item.get(byKey));
  this.data.splice(index, 1);
  return index != -1 ? true : false;
 }

 getAll(): Array<T> {
  return this.data;
 }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

I think i got you from the screenshot you share. You want to provide only properties that is not function. But you can't achieve it directly via generics. You also need help of the mapped types. What we need is a mapped typed that filters non functional properties. For that we need at least 2 mapped types one with filtering key and the other making a type with that filtered keys like below:

```js
type FilteredKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T];

type NonFunctionalProperties<T> = { [Q in FilteredKeys<T>]: T[Q] };
```

And then your function description will become like below :

```js
 remove<J extends keyof NonFunctionalProperties<T>>(item: T, byKey: J): boolean {
        let index = this.data.findIndex((i: T) => i[byKey] === item[byKey]);
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
        return index != -1 ? true : false;
    }
```

Usage

```
collection.remove(c,"name") // ok
collection.remove(c,"get") // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIDECWAbU0BO0AmBpa4BnAHgBUA+WAXlgG9YBtABVkQDtYBrfAewDNYSAXQBcApoNjQAHmlZYCCAK6sAxqETd2AflitoANwyxRzAL70u4PgMEBuEBBiwAcpvjK1G1gENkjdNww6OrQxORUtAwAiizsSKgY2HiEpGQiYlESpvbA0pDcwbDeAEYEoOjearAqyN4ECgDC3MjI0J6apAA0sDgUNMCwg7CQ6Ij63miwWBPeogCC6BXgqRH0diBDRVhYABSIaAC2oiQAlKL63IhYtAObQ6AAFogEAHTToN4vkIoED3uHJ3sm1MGyGmAO3EMRAAUpIZNA5ApLNZXKx3Kp1JpfP5AhgQmEyGR-tAjgJusVwMlRNCzrBitxmtBvOx+nchq1QLEsNIIo9nm8Zi9eGwsABJOTSHZ7Y4nKgURD0CnJCSUVUsQ6Kyn4QSA25svmvd6fAiQZCIFTQPYSqTdACMurZg0woEU6HYIp5AEJqABaW2wHTlRRwUS8XwEaBAoYgvWwADm0FAcxaO1pCyWK1ZjudrvYBoFHyjgxBMZqdUaE2gcYK4Czgx8B2gojKo1YcdgAB9YMpucK9Fgi7BeAzm+U2O2uz3oH3sIOE6BUzdHbBYzHNhGF7K63dVyBS5oytUInoAO6wBqV6vocCp+yOOAARwi8TQmFw+GIF7QV-AZHsZfqc9K3QH8mhaNpMXYaRZHkc9mladp2CIIDvxrbovyrGtYD6TYQGAEF727a5qBbcdO27CUZwHYAVAPTlaPAxDj2gM8MJAmswIQyDbxo+CIK8F5vG2HYVF1BiuIE8FIUtFRugAImHbg5NlAB6FT1QUbgOF4xjIJeKTDBE+T52U2xYDUyRFgKPCQCAA)